# Create all sequences from the first item within a list

Tags: python

Say I have a list, `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`. Are there any built-ins or methods in Python to easily create all **contiguous sublists** (i.e. sub-sequences) starting from the first item?:

```
['a']
['a', 'b']
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

in Python?

Note that I am excluding lists/sequences such as `['a' ,'c']`,  `['a', 'd']`, `['b']`, `['c']` or `['d']`

Comment: you know that's not ALL sublists, right ?

Comment: What about `['b', 'c']` , `['b', 'd']` etc?

Comment: Are you looking for consecutive sequences?

Comment: This isn't even all contiguous sublists...you aren't including ['b', 'c'], ['c', 'd'], and ['b', 'c', 'd'].

Comment: @ShashankGupta, I said **starting from the first item**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To match your example output (prefixes), then you can just use:

```
prefixes = [your_list[:end] for end in xrange(1, len(your_list) + 1)]
```

Comment: Should be `xrange(1, len(your_list) + 1)`.

Comment: Or `range(1, len(your_list) + 1)` in Python 3.x

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a simple [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> 
>>> [l[:i+1] for i in range(len(l))]
[['a'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
```

See also: [`range()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)

If you're using Python 2.x, use [`xrange()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) instead.

Answer (score 1):

A little more Pythonic than using `(x)range` (with the benefit of being the same solution for either Python 2 or Python 3):

```
lst = list('abcde')
prefixes = [ lst[:i+1] for i,_ in enumerate(lst) ]
```

If you decided that the empty list should be a valid (zero-length) prefix, a small hack will include it:

```
# Include 0 as an slice index and still get the full list as a prefix
prefixes = [ lst[:i] for i,_ in enumerate(lst + [None]) ]
```

Comment: I'm not sure that it's more Pythonic to use `enumerate` but throw away half of its return data, and keep only the part which is exactly what `range` would have given you.

Comment: I'm using 'Flat is better than nested' (`enumerate` vs `(x)range` and `len`) and 'Explicit is better than implicit' ( `i` is the result of enumerating over the input list) in my interpretation of 'pythonic' here. Just providing my thought process.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an alternative:

```
def prefixes(seq):
    result = []
    for item in seq:
        result.append(item)
        yield result[:]

for x in prefixes(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']):
    print(x)
```